# Disable OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider in Spring-Security-Core 5.7.11

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In the course of the Spring-Boot migration I am currently changing from Spring Security 5.3.9.RELEASE to 5.7.11. I have the problem that my AuthenticationProvider, which I create with a custom OIDC Auth, always ends up last in my list of providers and therefore always uses the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider indexed by Spring, which then flies around my ears later in the application. Now the question arises as to how I can switch this off?

In the first for loop I have the following 3 providers here, where I want to use the last one:

- AnonymousAuthenticationProvider
- OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider
- **OIDCAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider**

It's about the ProviderManager.java class in the spring-security-core-5.7.11 package and the method in it:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    Class<? extends Authentication> toTest = authentication.getClass();
    AuthenticationException lastException = null;
    AuthenticationException parentException = null;
    Authentication result = null;
    Authentication parentResult = null;
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int size = this.providers.size();
    for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
        if (!provider.supports(toTest)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace(LogMessage.format("Authenticating request with %s (%d/%d)",
                    provider.getClass().getSimpleName(), ++currentPosition, size));
        }
        try {
            result = provider.authenticate(authentication);
            if (result != null) {
                copyDetails(authentication, result);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (AccountStatusException | InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex) {
            prepareException(ex, authentication);
            // SEC-546: Avoid polling additional providers if auth failure is due to
            // invalid account status
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }
    if (result == null && this.parent != null) {
        // Allow the parent to try.
        try {
            parentResult = this.parent.authenticate(authentication);
            result = parentResult;
        }
        catch (ProviderNotFoundException ex) {
            // ignore as we will throw below if no other exception occurred prior to
            // calling parent and the parent
            // may throw ProviderNotFound even though a provider in the child already
            // handled the request
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            parentException = ex;
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }
    if (result != null) {
        if (this.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication && (result instanceof CredentialsContainer)) {
            // Authentication is complete. Remove credentials and other secret data
            // from authentication
            ((CredentialsContainer) result).eraseCredentials();
        }
        // If the parent AuthenticationManager was attempted and successful then it
        // will publish an AuthenticationSuccessEvent
        // This check prevents a duplicate AuthenticationSuccessEvent if the parent
        // AuthenticationManager already published it
        if (parentResult == null) {
            this.eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Parent was null, or didn't authenticate (or throw an exception).
    if (lastException == null) {
        lastException = new ProviderNotFoundException(this.messages.getMessage("ProviderManager.providerNotFound",
                new Object[] { toTest.getName() }, "No AuthenticationProvider found for {0}"));
    }
    // If the parent AuthenticationManager was attempted and failed then it will
    // publish an AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent
    // This check prevents a duplicate AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent if the
    // parent AuthenticationManager already published it
    if (parentException == null) {
        prepareException(lastException, authentication);
    }
    throw lastException;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to exclude these 2 auto-configuration ?

Comment: Problem was that my scope didn't contain openid as scope, which resulted in a wrong usage of the oauth2 client